# how to customize angular toaster message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, toastr

I am using angular-file-upload. I have setup a batch file upload that parse's the file names and matched them to properties stored in a database. The files need to be structured like this.

> 01-1998 VRF RD678.pdf

VRF is the name of a pipeline
RD is the name of a location
678 is the number of a location code

they each have there own if statement to check for files that do match anything in the database. right now if something does not match or is named improperly this appears
[image: errorPic]

I would like to do 3 things.

1. define a error message that shows the file name and the specific if statement that errors out. if there is no match for the pipeline i want the file name and "no match for pipeline" underneath.
2. define a error message for when the structure of the file name is incorrect. i want the file name with "incorrect filename" underneath
3. prevent the function from error out, I would like the error messages to be displayed and allow the other files to be uploaded

I am trying to use linq.js, javascript is ok as well.

here is what i am trying to make work, this example is when a file is not structured correctly. this error message is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
$scope.upload = function () {
    var files = $scope.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            $scope.pipes.map(function (pip) {
                $scope.pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
            });
            $scope.locations.map(function (loc) {
                $scope.locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
            });
            $scope.locationCodes.map(function (locCode) {
                $scope.locationCodeLookup[locCode['LocationCodeAb']] = locCode;
            });
            var matchesPip = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*(\S*\s*)(\S*)/i);
            var matchesLoc = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)(\d+)\./i);
            var matchesLocCode = file.name.match(/^(\d+\D\d+)\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)(\d+)\./i);
            $scope.pip = $scope.pipeLookup[matchesPip[1]];
            $scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matchesLoc[2]];
            $scope.locCode = $scope.locationCodeLookup[matchesLocCode[4]];
            if ($scope.pip == null) {

                $scope.pip = Enumerable.From(files)
                            .Where("x => x.files.name != '" + matchesPip[0] + "'").ToArray();

                toaster.pop('error', matchesPip[0]);
                console.log(matchesPip[0])
            }
            if ($scope.loc == null) {
                toaster.pop('error', matchesLoc[0]);
                console.log(matchesLoc[0])
            }
            if ($scope.locCode == null) {
                toaster.pop('error', matchesLocCode[0]);
                console.log(matchesLocCode[0])
            }
            $upload.upload({
                url: '/api/apiBatchPipeLine',
                fields: {
                    'typeId': 1,
                    'companyId': $scope.companyId.CompanyId,
                    'companyName': $scope.companyId.CompanyName,
                    'documentDate': $scope.model.documentDate,
                    'pipeId': $scope.pip['PipeId'],
                    'pipeName': $scope.pip['PipeName'],
                    'locationId': $scope.loc['LocationId'],
                    'locationAb': $scope.loc['LocationAb'],
                    'locationCodeId': $scope.locCode['LocationCodeId'],
                    'locationCodeAb': $scope.locCode['LocationCodeAb']
                },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                toaster.pop('success', config.file.name);
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
            }).error(function (err, result, config) {
                toaster.pop('error', config.file.name);
                console.log(err, result);
            });

        }
    }
};
```

[image: pic2]
[image: pic1]

Comment: If it's when the file error's out then you should be focusing on this line `toaster.pop('error', config.file.name);`. The `config` object has no `file` object. My guess is because it's actually `result.file.name`.

Comment: Likely that `config.file` is not set (is undefined) on this line `toaster.pop('error', config.file.name);`

Comment: instead of third party go for a custom global directive.

Comment: Can you share what directive I should use

Comment: use matrial angular library. toast is really easy there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ngFileUpload `error` event callback receives 4 arguments as in:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/dist/ng-file-upload-all.js#L509-514

```
promise.error = function (fn) {
   promise.then(null, function (response) {
       fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
   });
   return promise;
};
```

`headers` is the 3rd argument, `config` is the 4th argument. In your code `config` is referencing `headers`. `headers.file` is undefined so this is how you get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Change:

```
.error(function (err, result, config) {
   ...
})
```

To:

```
.error(function (err, result, headers, config) {
   ...
})
```